# What is the highest FlyingSaucer R8 compatible Itext?

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

The FS distro comes bundled with IText 2.0.8 and given that are many more recent releases in the 2.x.x range i was wondering if anyone had any experiences in more recent releases. I am guesssing there is a chance FS might also be compatible with 3.x.x.x +...

Anybody know/confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried 2.1.7 and it has some class (API) changes which cause Flying Saucer to get linkageerrors...so i n short no it would appear that 2.0.8 is the latest supported version.

Comment: itext 2.17 works now with flying-saucer-pdf 9.06 (which pulls in 2.17 as a dep).

Answer (score 1):

To answer a related question of whether there is any version of flyingsaucer which is compatible with iText 5.x, the answer is yes.

I believe that, since [ollo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145691/854151), there has been a restructuring of the project to make it more maven friendly, and instead of there being a separate itext5 branch, there is now a separate itext5 maven artifact. Find it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer.

I think the core-renderer artifact is the old artifact they used, and can be replaced with flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 for iText5 compatibility. This new artifact has a single external dependency, and that is group `com.itextpdf`, artifact `itextpdf` and version 5.x. I tried with version 5.4.5, and that worked fine for me.

Comment: +1 just to clarify for anyone wanting to use iText5, iText 2.17 is the *last* version prior to switch to AGPL, so iText > 2.17 *without* purchasing commmercial support means *your application source code* must be made publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

With the itext5 branch it's possible to use Flying Saucer with iText 5.x too.

> Release 8 supports version 2.x of iText, was shipped with 2.0.8 and we
>   have users who report using 2.1.7; we believe 2.1.7 should be more or
>   less identical to 4.2.0.
>
> For iText 5.x support, we do have a contributed itext5 branch on
>   GitHub though for anybody using iText 5+. The changes were mostly just
>   package renames along with a couple of other tweaks. We keep the
>   itext5 branch in sync with master so it should always be current.

*source:* http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQPDF#Versions_of_iText_Supported

See also: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/tree/itext5

Answer (score 0):

Note that iText 5.x is distributed with the AGPL license which is restrictive with what you are allowed to do (see http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/). 
iText 2.1.7 / 4.2.0 is distributed with the LGPL / MPL license and are safer to use.

Also, there is a newer version of Flying Saucer Renderer which uses iText 2.1.7.

See 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf/9.0.1

The maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```